# Facebook API publish_pages, manage_pages not working properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook `publish_pages` and `manage_pages` permissions not working properly.

I checked the `access_token` in **Access Token Debugger** and I can see both of these permissions. However, when I try to post something, it throws out an error.

`{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"BFnDU4HeBsR"}}1`

If I try and do the same thing with the `access_token` that I grab from **Graph API Explorer** it seems to work fine.

[image]

Comment: Where are you trying to post? What kind of token did you get from Graph API Explorer?

Comment: Page token with publish action.

Comment: Well you need publish_pages to post as a page.

Comment: @CBroe If you check the attached image above, I do have the `publish_pages` permission as well.

Comment: Then your page access token likely is not a page access token.